# Deploying Vaults from solana-program-library

Tags: vault

From the [Quick Start](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/farms/docs/quick_start.md) guide, I am trying to deploy a vault for a pool I already deployed in devnet ("2cr3zUsQMFNPB22Tszd3FVyS5o3kr3Fgq5wkRgZ5faX2"), I am having some questions for which I can t find answer in the guide nor here:

- How can I switch between devnet and mainnet, is it the same as `solana config set url --devnet` but with solana-farm-ctrl ?
- How can I deploy the vault that works for the pool I have? I mean, is not like in Solidity where the program has a constructor and when deploying you set the info like pool, token A, token B, how this goes in Solana?
- Finally, solana-farm-ctrl vault-init all is not working, the error says it requires a  but is not defined in the docs.

Comment: Switching is as you say `solana config set -h`

Answer (score 1):

Devnet and mainey are different and u have to create the pool again in mainnet
And then u can use that account to interact

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, not many liquidity protocols are fully available on devnet. Raydium, for example, only has a test Pool with PC and COIN tokens. So, you can't initialize a Vault for the Pool and Farm that are not available on devnet.

The quick start guide has examples of how to upload metadata for mainnet-beta pools. If you are trying to use devnet, replace metadata filenames with corresponding "_dev.json" versions, e.g. `solana-farm-ctrl  -k main_admin.json load --skip-existing Pool farm-ctrl/metadata/pools/raydium/pools_dev.json`. Again, not all tokens/pools/farms are available on devnet, so if you don't see "_dev.json" version, it means there is none.

If you get to the point where you correctly uploaded metadata for the Vault and still getting an error while trying to initialize it, post the output of `solana-farm-ctrl get-all vault` and the error you are getting, and I'll try to help.

Comment: I can't  update metadata because when I try to Initialize the storage (solana-farm-ctrl --keypair main_admin.json init-all), I get an error because: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid instruction data.
Basically appears the addres of solana_router_main.so invoke [1].
I can 't continue as I need the RefDB init

Comment: It looks like you created a separate question, so I'll answer it [there](https://solana.stackexchange.com/q/4539/346)