# Problem with initialize storage data (Solana program library)

Tags: deploy, storage, vault

I can't update metadata because when I try to Init the storage
`solana-farm-ctrl --keypair main_admin.json init-all`
I get an error because: Error processing Instruction 0: invalid instruction data. Basically appears the addres of solana_router_main.so invoke [1]. I can 't continue as I need the RefDB init
This is the address of the solana_router_main.so deployment
92dU166h998B8tY1jRE8tvi7PwG4vFvUNDBKkGxB7gVS
I have enough balance to deploy programs so I have no idea why I can init the storage.
I am using this guide: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/farms/docs/quick_start.md

Answer (score 1):

The quick start guide is for mainnet and your router appears to be uploaded to devnet. I described a bit how to tune it for devnet [here](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/4409/346). But there might be other changes to configs that are needed. I'll try to update the guide for devnet next week.
Edit: [devnet guide](https://github.com/solana-labs/farms/blob/master/docs/quick_start_devnet.md)

Comment: Noted, i will keep trying while waiting for the guide update, thank you!

Comment: Added link to the [devnet guide](https://github.com/solana-labs/farms/blob/master/docs/quick_start_devnet.md)

Comment: I don't see in the changes a fix for the problem, if I try to init the storage I keep getting errors because of the Main Router incorrect program id for instruction.
 incorrect program id for instruction", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(0, IncorrectProgramId)), logs: Some(["Program 9jQAXSLS3VabeRXV2YfPBKpcVADSDDqfaPTH2mdL6Dqk invoke [1]", "Program log: Main router entrypoint", "Program 9jQAXSLS3VabeRXV2YfPBKpcVADSDDqfaPTH2mdL6Dqk , "Program 9........ failed: incorrect program id for instruction"])

Comment: you need to follow instructions precisely. I tried myself and didn't encounter any errors. But you can't recover from a bad state if you used mainnet instructions. Just start over. Generate new keys for main router, admin etc. to make sure you are not colliding with invalid data.